# What is the maximum number of ways this set of numbers can multiple to 1?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Fix $n\geq 2$ and a bitstring $b \in \{0,1\}^n$, and consider the product of real numbers
$$
a_1^{(b_1)}\cdot a_2^{(b_2)}\cdot \cdots \cdot a_n^{(b_n)}
$$
where $a_i^{(0)}\in (0,1]$ and $a_i^{(1)} \in (1,2]$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Of all $2^n$ possible products corresponding to different choices of $b \in \{0, 1\}^n$ with $b = b_1\cdots b_n$, what is the maximum number of products such that
$$
a_1^{(b_1)}\cdot a_2^{(b_2)}\cdot \cdots \cdot a_n^{(b_n)} = 1?
$$

Comment: Are the $a_i^{b_j}$ all pairwise different?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni the $a_i^{b_j}$ need not be pairwise distinct.

Comment: Then for $n$ even, $n=2k$, you can have for example $\forall i, a_i^{(0)}=0.5$ and  $a_i^{(1)} = 2$. The product equals $1$ when half of $b_j$'s are $0$. Which means $2k \choose k$ configurations. And you want to find the sets of $a_i^{(0)}, a_i^{(1)}$ that maximise this quantity, is it correct?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni yes that is correct.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni specifically, I am wondering if this $2k \choose k$ value is indeed the maximum for any choice of the $a_i^{b_j}$, so for such a choice of $a_i^{b_j}$, what is the biggest proportion of the product choices that equals 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** The maximum number of products is always $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }$.

For each subset $S$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, let $a_S$ be the product corresponding to $S$, meaning that the result of setting $b_i=1$ when $i\in S$ and $b_i=0$ when $i\notin S$ in $a_1^{b_1}\cdots a_n^{b_n}$. Then, let $\mathscr C$ be the family of subsets for which $a_S=1$. You want the maximum possible size of $\mathscr C$.

Note that, for any distinct sets $S, T\in \mathscr C$, it is impossible for $S\subseteq T$. This is because whenever $S$ and $T$ are distinct subsets where $S\subseteq T$, we have $a_S<a_T$ (every factor is greater or equal, and at least one factor is strictly greater), so you cannot have $a_S=a_T=1$. By definition, this implies that $\mathscr C$ is an *antichain*. We can then apply [Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) to conclude that
$$
|\mathscr C|\le \binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }.
$$
This bound is always attainable. In the case where $n$ is even, this is done by setting $a^{(0)}_i=1/2$ and $a^{(1)}_i=2$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. In the case where $n$ is odd, you instead can let
$$
a^{(0)}_i= (1/2)^{2/(n-1)}\qquad a^{(1)}_i=2^{{2}/({n+1})} .
$$
This means the only way to attain a product of $1$ is to have exactly $(n+1)/2$ elements in $S$, so
$$
a_1^{b_1}\cdots a_n^{b_n}=\left((1/2)^{2/(n-1)}\right)^{(n-1)/2}\cdot \left(2^{2/(n+1)}\right)^{(n+1)/2}=1.
$$